# Can Docker plugins inspect label metadata from starting image?

Tags: plugins, docker, docker-compose

I'm asking if it's possible to have a docker volume plugin inspect a starting image's label metadata in order to take some additional action? I'd like to see said action include mounting a *device*, but I'm not sure if such is yet possible with a *driver* plugin, nor have I seen any mention of say device plugin lately.

I'm trying to see if there are ways to enable the nvidia-docker-plugin in the scope of docker-compose files like so:

```
test:
  image: ubuntu
  volume_driver: nvidia-docker-driver
  labels:
    nvidia.gpu: "0,1"
  command: nvidia-smi
```

Relevant issue with context: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/39

Answer (score 0):

Just resurrecting this old issue to say that this is now solved by [nvidia-docker-compose](https://github.com/eywalker/nvidia-docker-compose).